# Set MenuItem text Center Align in Navigation View in Android

Tags: android, menuitem, navigationview

I need to Set MenuItem text align center inside Navigation view android searching for that from past one week please someone help

Answer (score 1):

You can center-align the menu items dynamically using `SpannableString` in your activity:

```
int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);
s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

item.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle); what is settingsitem title

Comment: @Murali: the String used for this item.i.e. title as defined `android:title`